# How to get same monitor when calling notifyAll()?

Tags: java, multithreading

main thread creating two thread t1 and t2 run() method of these thread creating two new thread c1 and c2.I want a scenario such that until c1&c2(of t1) are alive t2 will not start executing.
In my code notify and wait are causing Runtime Exception.Since they are not in synchronised block, how to do this?

```
public class childTcreat2newthread {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread mainT=Thread.currentThread();
        Target ra=new Target("a");
        Thread t1=new Thread(ra);
        t1.start();
        t1.join();

        while(ra.getC1().isAlive()==true||ra.getC2().isAlive()==true){
        synchronized (mainT) {
        mainT.wait();
        }}
        new Thread(new Target("b")).start();}}



class Target implements Runnable{
    Thread c1=new Thread(new Target1("1"));

    Thread c2=new Thread(new Target1("2"));
    String msg;
    Target(String msg){
        this.msg=msg;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {


        for(int j=0;j<100000;j++){
            for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
                if(i%10000==0&&j%10000==0){System.out.print(msg);}
            }}

        t1.start();

        t2.start();
    }

    public Thread getC1(){return c1;}
    public Thread getC2(){return c2;}
}

class Target1 implements Runnable   {

    String msg;
    Target1(String msg){
        this.msg=msg;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        for(int j=0;j<100000;j++){
            for(int i=0;i<100000;i++){
                if(i%100000==0&&j%10000==0){System.out.print(msg);}
            }
        }
        try{

        notifyAll();
        System.out.println("K");}catch(IllegalMonitorStateException e){System.out.println("\nIllegalMonitorStateException!! in "+msg+"\n");}
    }
}
```

wait( ) tells the calling thread to give up the monitor and go to sleep until some others thread enters the same monitor and calls notify( ).**Unable to get same monitor when calling notify**.How to do this?

As for my understanding both the thread t1 & t2 does not have common object here to which these are accessing so which object we should have to pass in synchronised lock to call wait() and notify()?

Comment: Don't synchronize and call wait/notify/notifyAll on an Thread object. Read the javadoc of wait() and notifyAll(). Use join() to wait for threads to end.

Comment: You `while` loop needs to be inside the `synchronized` block. Otherwise, you're checking `isAlive` without protection. (If `isAlive` is `synchronized` itself, you still have a race condition. It can change state after `isAlive` returns and you call `wait` for something that already happened.)

Comment: May i suggest to use the classes of java.util.concurrent? It wrap the complexity of wait/notify. I think a Semaphore(2) would do the trick, with 2 release in the threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @JB Nizet pointed out you should use join to wait fot thread termination

**EDIT** 
since you cannot use join I suggest you to use a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) since
its documentation states:

> A synchronization aid that allows one or more threads to wait until a set of operations being performed in other threads completes.

Which is what you asked for.

**SECOND EDIT**

Here is a modified version of your code that wait for thread termination using a **HomeMade** CountDownLatch that uses wait and notify.

```
    import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class childTcreat2newthread {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MyCountDownLatch doneSignal = new MyCountDownLatch(2);

        Target ra = new Target("a",doneSignal);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(ra);
        t1.start();
        doneSignal.await();
        System.out.println("after await ");
        MyCountDownLatch doneSignal1 = new MyCountDownLatch(2);
        new Thread(new Target("b",doneSignal1)).start();
    }
}

class Target implements Runnable {
    private Thread c1;
    private Thread c2;
    String msg;


    Target(String msg, MyCountDownLatch doneSignal) {
        this.msg = msg;

        c1 = new Thread(new Target1("1",doneSignal));

        c2 = new Thread(new Target1("2",doneSignal));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Start of Target " + msg);
        for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                if (i % 10000 == 0 && j % 10000 == 0) {
                    System.out.print(msg);
                }
            }
        }

        c1.start();

        c2.start();
//      try {
//          c1.join();
//          c2.join();
//      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
        System.out.println("End of Target " + msg);

    }

    public Thread getC1() {
        return c1;
    }

    public Thread getC2() {
        return c2;
    }
}

class Target1 implements Runnable {

    String msg;
    private MyCountDownLatch doneSignal;

    Target1(String msg, MyCountDownLatch doneSignal) {
        this.msg = msg;
        this.doneSignal=doneSignal;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Start of Target1 " + msg);
        for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                if (i % 100000 == 0 && j % 10000 == 0) {
                    System.out.print(msg);
                }
            }
        }
        try {

            System.out.println("K");
            doneSignal.countDown();
            System.out.println("End of Target1 " + msg);
        } catch (IllegalMonitorStateException e) {
            System.out.println("\nIllegalMonitorStateException!! in " + msg
                    + "\n");
        }
    }
}

class MyCountDownLatch {
    private int waitersNum;

    public MyCountDownLatch(int waitersNum) {
        this.waitersNum=waitersNum;
    }

    public synchronized void countDown() {
        waitersNum--;
        if (waitersNum==0) {
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void await() throws InterruptedException {
        wait();
    }       
}
```

Comment: your code is looking good(will start t2 after c1 & c2) but this does not resolve my problem,actually i want to use notify() method to notify the main thread that is currently in sleep.I am Unable to get same monitor when calling notify() method.

Comment: thanks man,you are again right but I want to use notify() or notifyAll() in my code,actually this is a sample code I submitted here but in my real time  application I have to use notify() or notifyAll() method to resume the main thread.@Giovanni

Answer (score 0):

notify, notifyAll, wait calls should be done in the monitor of the same object. There should be a shared object like `Object` and you should build your logic around that. For example :

```
public class ClassA{

    Object lockObject=new Object(); 

    //Thread A will call this method
    public void  methodA(){
         synchronized(lockObject){
             while(!aCondition)
                 lockObject.wait();
         }
    }
    //Thread B will call this method
    public void  methodB(){
         synchronized(lockObject){
             aCondition=true;
             lockObject.notify();
         }
    }

}
```